# Generic Task Method Implementation

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm, task, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel which inherites from ViewModelBase.
Currently I am calling my services in my ViewModel like this:

```
private void Login(string _username,  string _password)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      var isLoginSuccess = await _authenticationDataService.Login(_username, _password);
      if (isLoginSuccess == true) { }
    });
}
```

In my AuthenticarionService it looks like this:

```
  public async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        Token = await GetAPIToken(username, password);
        return true;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password)
    {
       //Blah blah blah wont bore you with the detail
    }
```

Now what I want is to put a generic Task method that will run any "awaitables" I pass to it and return a generic result (I can cast the result correctly in my viewmodel) in my ViewModelBase.

So that I can do something of this sort:

```
private void Login(string _username,  string _password)
{
   var serviceCall = _authenticationDataService.Login(_username, _password);//Should not execute at this point yet
   var loginSuccessfull = someTaskInMyViewModelBase(serviceCall);

}
```

My goal here is that every viewmodel that inherites the viewmodelbase have this generic method available to pass in their serviceCalls. There is a IsBusy property in the Viewmodelbase which binds to a busy indicator on the view. And I dont like to implement it as Isbusy = true before I call the service and IsBusy = false after the call was done. If I have a generic service method in the viewmodelBase I can stick it in there and it will work automatically for any viewmodel: This goes the same for storing Errors in the viewmodelbase. I want to handle it all in this generic method. Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Why is `Login` in your view model synchronous anyway? If you are consuming asynchronous code, it should be asynchronous as well.

Comment: Aren't you basically describing exactly the functionality that's already provided by `Task<T>`? Given your requirements, I don't really see then need for another layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run **any** awaitable.

You could do something like that

```
private async Task<T> RunTask<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    T result = await task;
    return result;
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want before and after `T result = await task;`.

Comment: Thanks a million, this is what I wanted